# How to access /var/run/docker.sock from inside a docker container as a non-root user? (MacOS Host)

Tags: macos, docker

I have installed docker on Mac and everything is running fine. I am using a Jenkins docker image and running it. While using Jenkins as a CI server and to build further images by running docker commands through it, I came to know that we have to bind mount `/var/run/docker.sock` while running the Jenkins images so it can access the docker daemon.

I did that, and installed docker CLI inside Jenkins’s container. But when running `docker ps` or any other docker commands it is throwing an error:

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.28/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

When I connect to container as a root user, it works fine. But switching to the ‘jenkins’ user throws the above error. I have already added ‘jenkins’ user to sudo list but does not help.

I found few articles suggesting to add ‘jenkins’ user to ‘docker’ group but to my surprise I do not find any docker group on Mac or inside container.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Docker > File-Sharing... `/var` is not shared by default

Comment: Or https://serverfault.com/a/659043

Comment: though not cool but modifying the permission of /var/run/docker.sock fixed the issue. I have provided the appropriate permission to jenkins user to /var/run/docker.sock file and it worked fine.

Comment: Hey Neeraj, have you done a chmod on /var/run/docker.sock?

Comment: @TibinPaul, yes. I had to provide permission to my user for  /var/run/docker.sock.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like the reason this is happening is pretty straight forward: UNIX permissions are not letting the `jenkins` user read `/var/run/docker.sock`. Really the easiest option is to just change the group assignment on `/var/run/docker.sock` from `root` to another group, and then add `jenkins` to that group:

```
[as root, inside the container]
root@host:/# usermod -G docker jenkins
root@host:/# chgrp docker /var/run/docker.sock
```

This assumes of course that you already have the docker CLI installed, and that a group called `docker` exists. If not:

```
[as root, inside the container]
root@host:/# groupadd docker
```

Alternatively, you could change the world permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock` to allow non-root users to access the socket, but I wouldn't recommend doing that; it just seems like bad security practice. Similarly, you could outright `chown` the socket to the `jenkins` user, although I'd rather just change the group settings.

---

I'm confused why using `sudo` didn't work for you. I just tried what I believe is exactly the setup you described and it worked without problems.

Start the container:

```
[on macos host]
darkstar:~$ docker run \
                  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \  
                  docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:lts
darkstar:~$ docker exec -u root -it <container id> /bin/bash
```

Install Docker CLI:

```
[as root, inside container]
root@host:/# apt-get update
root@host:/# apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
                                ca-certificates \
                                curl \
                                gnupg2 \
                                software-properties-common
root@host:/# rel_id=$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")
root@host:/# curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/${rel_id}/gpg > /tmp/dkey
root@host:/# apt-key add /tmp/dkey
root@host:/# add-apt-repository \
             "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/${rel_id} \
              $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
root@host:/# apt-get update
root@host:/# apt-get -y install docker-ce
```

Then set up the jenkins user:

```
[as root, inside container]
root@host:/# usermod -G sudo jenkins
root@host:/# passwd jenkins
[...]
```

And trying it out:

```
[as jenkins, inside container]
jenkins@host:/$ sudo docker ps -a
[...]
password for jenkins:

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED     ...
69340bc13bb2        jenkins/jenkins:lts   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   8 minutes ago ...
```

it seems to work fine for me. Maybe you took a different route to install the Docker CLI? Not sure, but if you want to access the docker socket using `sudo`, those steps will work. Although, I think it would be easier to just change the group assignment as explained up above. Good luck :)

---

**Note**: All tests performed using macOS Mojave v10.14.3 running Docker Engine v19.03.2. This doesn't seem to be heavily dependent on the host platform, so I would expect it to work on Linux or any other UNIX-like OS, including other versions of macOS/OSX.

Comment: Do you realize we are on MacOSX ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa I ran this on my Macbook Pro. I guess technically I am on macOS and not OSX (since Apple rebranded it) but it should not make a difference. This issue appears to be related to setup from within the container and not on the host OS.

Comment: I added a note on the test platform. Maybe I am misunderstanding, but it sounds to me like this: OSX is being used as the host system to run a Jenkins CI build server inside a docker container. The Jenkins server requires the ability to control the provisioning of other containers on the OSX host, but from within it's own container (thus the bind mount of `/var/run/docker.sock`). There has been some difficulty in granting access to that socket inside of the container to the `jenkins` user. If that is correct, this answer should be the solution. If I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: I am not even running a single docker container, my issue is having another user than root being able to use `docker` on MacOSx, not being able to have a user within a container to access docker socket. But I admit, this question was half mine, half within a docker container. I will accept your answer and give you the bounty even if I still can't use `docker` cli in my MacOSx without `root`

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa That sounds very strange. Are you using Docker Desktop, or something older (ie. Docker Toolkit)?? I am using Docker Desktop and I don't have that issue. If you can, perhaps try uninstalling whatever you are using currently, and try the latest Docker Desktop. Make sure you don't have VirtualBox prior to version 4.3.30 installed, and also make sure to unset any `DOCKER_*` environment variables that might have been set by the old installation. Both of those can cause issues when switching to Docker Desktop. You might want to start a new question if the problem is ongoing.

Comment: I have install docker-cli equivalent on mac, I think it is called docker desktop yes.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa if your context is different from that of the OP, in the future please post a separate question rather than send the comment section on a tangent

Comment: This is a problem because it creates a group permissions issue outside the container....if you make the group docker inside the container you lose access to docker.sock outside....srw-rw---- 1 root systemd-coredump 0 Feb 10 01:14 /var/run/docker.sock

Answer (score -1):

No, but this works:

- Add the user (e.g. `jenkins`) to the `staff`-group: `sudo dseditgroup -o edit -a jenkins -t user staff`
- Allow group to sudo, in `sudo visudo` add:

  `%staff ALL = (ALL) ALL`

Comment: This break system permissions, staff is not an admin and it should not be.