# Jenkins Docker Socket

Tags: macos, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, dockerfile

Jenkins docker.sock is not working.

I've already tried everything.

But i still get my error.

```
01:22:44 + docker ps
01:22:44 Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

This error disappears only when i run jenkins container as ROOT.

THIS IS WORKS FINE:

```
USER root

# prerequisites for docker
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        software-properties-common

# docker repos
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list \
    && echo "deb http://ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list \
    && apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 437D05B5 \
    && apt-get update

# docker
RUN apt-get -y install docker-ce

# docker-compose
RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.16.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# give jenkins docker rights
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

but when i add this to Dockerfile (using jenkins user instead of root)

```
# give jenkins docker rights
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

i get permission denied error.

I already tried this too:

```
newgrp docker
```

Not working

What i'm doing wrong?

My host OS is MacOS

It's okay to run jenkins as root or not?

Comment: Not sure how it works on mac but on linux you should add your user to docker group.

Comment: did you run jenkins with privileged mode?

Comment: @Adiii Yes, i did

Comment: @jaroslawj, why i need to add my host user to a docker group? I use docker in container

Comment: See answer there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391391/do-we-have-docker-group-on-mac?rq=1