# Update Docker Images via dockerized Jenkins Job

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, nas, synology

I run some docker containers on my Synology NAS. Now I also run Jenkins via Docker on the NAS and want to create a job that does the following steps:

- Stop all Docker Containers
- Delete all unnecessary stuff (-> docker system prune)
- Rebuild all Docker images
- Run the new Docker image

But I don't know how to access the host system in dockerized Jenkin. SSH to the Host doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Do you have any tips?

Comment: What you are actually trying to do is fundamentally the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58586495/6689725

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access /var/run/docker.sock from inside a docker container as a non-root user? (MacOS Host)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45391391/how-to-access-var-run-docker-sock-from-inside-a-docker-container-as-a-non-root)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of your Docker images is to run in an isolated sandbox, so it's by design that your image doesn't have access to the native system. SSH is one approach, but risky, as you point out.

A better approach is to set the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable to point to the IP of the NAS (which might need to be the virtual network NAS address).  You will probably need to experiment a bit with getting the correct address and making sure the hosted `docker` command has permissions to drive the host's Docker service.

[This post](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/102280) in the Synology Forums may get you on the right track.